# Change button-image using overrides

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I would like to change the image of the "Check out now" button in the cart view of VirtueMart. I know the image is located at `joomla_root/components/com_virtuemart/assets/images/vmgeneral/backgrounds.png` and that I could change it there.
But I fear that this change will be reverted once I update VirtueMart somewhen. I heared about overrides in Joomla, but I found no description how to use them for images.

**Edit**
The image seems to be used multiple times for different buttons. I want to change them all, so that's no problem - but I would like to avoid overriding every single file using this image.
The css-file for these buttons is located at `components/com_virtuemart/assets/css/vmsite-ltr.css`. Maybe it would be the best solution to override this file? This should change every button. But where do I have to locate the new css-file and the new image?

Answer (score 0):

In each template there is a "template" override folder... Usually at:

```
/templates/yourtemplate/html/
```

You can simply add another folder inside it for the component you wish to work on like so:

```
/templates/template_name/html/com_component/view_name/view_file.php
```

You have to figure out which view in virtumart uses your background image... then find the php file in that view and copy the file entirely to the path where you created for you override

Basically the file at

```
/templates/template/html/com_virtumart/view_name/view_file.php
```

Will override the one in the normal place like:

```
/components/com_virtuemart/views/view/tmpl/whereve.php
```

So when you update virtumart and it overrites the normal install path... your override file won't be touched!

Hope that helps

MORE SPECIFICALLY SOMETHING LIKE:

```
yoursite.com/templates/your_template/html/com_virtuemart/productdetails/default.php
```

Comment: Thank you! Cause the same images appears to be used for multiple buttons, I updated my question. Where do I have to locate a modified css-file? And where should I save the new image?